# Force compiler to use references from installed NuGet packages only instead of local DDLs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, roslyn

Is it possible to tell the compile to not load locally installed DLLs and use only the references provided by the installed NuGet-packages?

On our developer machines, there are various frameworks installed which are missing within our CI-environment. This often causes builds to fail and is very annoying to fix.

For example, on of my projects references `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` which works locally because the office-suite is installed on my machine. As soon as i run a build in the CI, the build fails because the office-suite is not installed on our agents.

**UPDATE**

The root of my problem is the following. I have some legacy software which did not use NuGet-Packages before. Locally, I can build those projects without any problems. But as soon as I trigger a CI build, the build fails as some references are not installed on the agent. I then have to search for the NuGet package that can replace the local reference and push the change to our git repo.

I would like to skip this time-consuming task of changing references, pushing then and waiting for the build to finish. If there was an option to tell the compiler to not using local references, I would get those same errors on my local machine.

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of reference you're talking about that is failing? Normally, if you want to tell the compiler to use nuget packages, you just use `<PackageReference>` in the csproj and you're done; if you're using other kinds of references: what are they?

Comment: @MarcGravell I've added an example. This problem mostly only occurs with older applications in our portfolio, as new projects are built using NuGet packages only

Comment: @mamen what does the xml element that imports the Interop.Word library into your .csproj file look like?

Comment: Depending on scale, you could remove the reference to the assembly and then install the NuGet package.

Comment: @phuzi that's basically what I am doing now, but I always have to wait for the CI build to finish. That's why I came up with the question. If i can tell the compile to not use any local references, I could get these errors on my machine and save a lot of time

Comment: If the the referenced assemblies in a specific location on your machine could delete/move them so the build cannot find them.

Comment: Also why just replace them all with NuGet packages in one go. I know it's painful but it's not something you'll need to do again in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have some legacy software which did not use NuGet-Packages before. Locally, I can build those projects without any problems. But as soon as I trigger a CI build, the build fails as some references are not installed on the agent.

Your projects will be referencing assemblies from the GAC, or via COM.

You want to disallow referencing any of these (other than the core assemblies that ship as part of your target framework).

To do this, search through all your project files (i.e. `.csproj` files) for any of the items of type `<Reference>` or `<COMReference>`. Any of these that reference non-framework assemblies should be removed and converted to `<PackageReference>` instead.

By "framework assembly" I mean things like `System.Windows.Forms` and so forth. Things that ship with .NET. The exact set depends upon what target framework you're targeting. I'm guessing it's some version of .NET Framework. If so, perhaps leave any `<Reference>` items matching `System.*` for now.

If a `<Reference>` has a `HintPath` that's a pretty good sign that it's being picked up locally from your machine too and should be converted.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the best option for me.

Comment: Glad to hear it sounds promising. How did you get on?

Comment: I opened all `.csproj` files and made a list of references that I need to replace. Then i replaced them all with NuGet packages. For the next legacy-project I need to integrate in our CI/CD systems, I will do this from the start.